# WebElement is locatable using cssSelector, xpath in the browser, while it is not null, but it is NotPresent, NotClickable, NotEnabled

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This may be a Selenium issue or Angular issue. I don't know..
I am having a button element with the following html code. This is an angular website, though.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-6 col-lg-3" css="1">
<button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" style="background-color: #00A6CA; border-color:#00A6CA;" type="button">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa tufa-plus-circle-o" style=""></span>
NEW EXTRACT 
</button>
</div>
```

I used xpath as ***//button[contains(text(),'NEW EXTRACT ')]*** and css Selector as **'button.btn.btn-secondary.pull-right'**. Both identified the button, very well, one on one (not multiple) in the browser console. When I used either of them in the page object code like...

```
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ is NOT null> "+(newExtractBtn != null));
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ to string> "+newExtractBtn.toString());
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ is present> "+newExtractBtn.isPresent());
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ Thread sleep for 10sec");
newExtractBtn.waitUntilEnabled();
System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ waited until enabled");
newExtractBtn.waitUntilPresent();
```

With an output of ...

```
I am getting out put as 
@@@@@@@@@@@ is NOT null> true
@@@@@@@@@@@ to string> ExtractExecutionHistoryPage.newExtractBtn
@@@@@@@@@@@ is present> false
@@@@@@@@@@@ Thread sleep for 10sec
```

As soon as it hits the webelement object `**newExtractBtn**`, it throws the following messages..

```
> net.thucydides.core.webdriver.exceptions.ElementShouldBeEnabledException: Expected enabled element was not enabled
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for ExtractExecutionHistoryPage.newExtractBtn to be enabled (tried for 5 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)
```

Why the webelement `newExtractBtn` is locatable in the browser with ***xpath, css*** and is visible on the webpage and also clickable is not-present and not-clickable during run time ?

Comment: are you sure the button identified by your code is the button you think it is? eg not some other button with text 'New Extract' that happens to be in the dom but not present or enabled? (did you try debugging?)

Answer (score 0):

### Two things...

1) You're making an assumption. Since the test fails due to the button not being "enabled", it never tests whether it's present. Since css and xpath found it, it's present, but your code never got that far.

2) Just because a button exists, doesn't mean it's enabled. It's possible for JavaScript to disable a button until certain criteria are met. It's not uncommon to start a page with the Submit button disabled until all values are entered and validated.

Comment: Whether I try to check **newExtractBtn.isEnabled()** or **newExtractBtn.isVisible()** or any thing which calls a method on the **newExtractBtn** an instance of  **WebElementFacade**, I am getting the corresponding exception being thrown. Saying either it is NOT enabled or visible or whatever I asked. As I mentioned, when checked for **(newExtractBtn != null)** returns **TRUE** though.

In the case of enabling the disabled button, for any reason, is there any Selenium or Serenity Java method ?

Comment: BTW, the page is mainly to display a table of results, not much of a form to fill any thing. It has got this 'new extract' button to go to the next page, where you would fill a form with items like name, criterion etc., 
Thus I don't know how this 'new extract' button being disabled for wanting the form to be filled.